# how can I determine if microsoft failover cluster has a quorum (in powershell)

Tags: powershell, failovercluster, alwayson

I'm trying to determine if my microsoft failover cluster has a quorum (in powershell).
Cmdlet **Get-ClusterQuorum** gives me quorum configuration - but I need a state.

Cmdlet **Get-Cluster | fl *** gives me a lot of cluster properties, but I cannot find there the one I need (**DynamicQuorum** is a configuration parameters and I would be happy if someone could explain me what **FixQuorum** and **PreventQuorum** exactly means, but probably they relate to **Start-ClusterNode -FixQuorum** command)

Since I have AlwaysOn high availability installed, I can run a query:

**select cluster_name, quorum_type_desc, quorum_state_desc from sys.dm_hadr_cluster**

and get something like:
myclustername,NODE_MAJORITY,**NORMAL_QUORUM**

and it seems what I need, but how can I get this without SQL?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**quorum_state_desc** shows whether your Cluster has NORMAL_QUORUM or FORCED_QUORUM state.
See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212952.aspx

Therefore, if you use

```
Get-Cluster | Select FixQuorum
```

you would get the same information.
**FixQuorum** can be 0 which equals NORMAL_QUORUM or 1 which equals FORCED_QUORUM. 
 See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342505(v=vs.85).aspx

And it is indeed related to:

```
Start-ClusterNode -FixQuorum
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270275.aspx